# TOAD sql editor - prompt when file changed?

Tags: toad

In TOAD, if I'm editing a sql file in the sql editor window and that file is changed (ie: by making an edit to it in Textpad), TOAD doesn't prompt you to get the changes.  Is there a way to get TOAD to give you a prompt?

Conversely, in Textpad if you have a file open and it is changed, Textpad will prompt you and ask if you want to reload the file with the changes.

**Edit**: We're using TOAD v. 8.6.1

Answer (score 5):

I understand you are using 8.6.1 so it maybe in a slightly different place but TOAD 10 has an option in the settings called "Prompt for reload on activation if timestamp has changed".

It is located under Editor->Open/Save.

Comment: That's exactly what we want.  Guess we need to upgrade!

Comment: The same option is also in 9.7.2.5 so it may be available in 8.6.1 however since I don't have that version installed I cannot confirm.

Comment: This is still correct as of Toad 13.2.0.258